# How do I access the clicked element ref from the handler function of a Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know that I can use `this.$refs` to access elements with the `ref` attribute set, but how do I access the `ref` for the clicked element? For example:

```
<div @click="clicked" ref="myRef"></div>

...

methods: {
    clicked: function($event) {
        var clickedElementRef = ???
    },
    
},
```

Just to explain what I am trying to do... I have a laod of navigation menu items, all of which trigger the same click handler e.g.

```
<li ref="dash" @click="showContent"></li>
<li ref="book" @click="showContent"></li>
<li ref="tick" @click="showContent"></li>
...
```

What I was hoping is that the `showContent` method would figure out the `ref` from the clicked element. The reason I want the ref is so that I can use it to show a page element whose `v-if` is bound to a data property in the Vue model that uses the respective ref e.g.

```
<div v-if="mainContent.dash.show">
<div v-if="mainContent.book.show">
<div v-if="mainContent.tick.show">
...
```

The `showContent` method would use `this.mainContent[clickedRef].show = true`. The reason I need a `ref` on the menu item is because I want to be able to trigger a menu item click programmatically e.g. `this.$refs['dash'].click()` in response to some other control showing the relevant content (so that the menu item goes through the same process as if it was clicked manually).

I was just trying to avoid duplicating some data e.g. having to do:

```
 <li ref="dash" @click="showContent('dash')"></li>
```

..but it's not a big deal. I'm still learning Vue and I'm coming from a HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery only background, so maybe there's a better way to do all of this.

Comment: `vm.$refs.myRef` is just link to your HTMLElement, it is not related to event. May be `@click="clicked($event)"`

Also why you need access to $event.target ?

Comment: Like Maxim pointed out this.$refs.myRef === $event.target. What are you trying to complish?

Comment: Your edit was helpful, but I think we'd be able to offer better suggestions if we saw a complete example of the problem. Can you provide a repro in Codepen/Codesandbox?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, but I'm gonna go a different way with this. With regard to the original question, I assume that it's not strictly possible to access the ref of the clicked element from the @click method. If that's true and someone wants to throw up an answer reflecting that, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass ref as second argument

```
<div ref="testClick" @click="testClick($event, 'testClick')" />

...

methods: {
  click($event, refKey) {
    const clickedElementRef = this.$refs[refKey];
  },
},
```

Comment: Yeah I knew about that, I was just trying to avoid duplicating the data entry because I have lots of menu options triggering the same method. So, I wanted to have the function just figure out what the clicked element ref is (also would be better when adding future menu options).